# Percorrer Arraylist de objetos de objetos e comparalos c#

Tags: c#, array, lista, arraylist

Eu estava querendo saber como eu consigo reutilizar o objeto que coloquei em um array list pois nao consigo comparar ele com nada, e como eu faço para comparar um objeto que esta dentro dele com outro, nesse programa da faculdade o objetivo era o usuario colocar o numero de formas que ele quisesse e colocar suas caracteristicas para eu depois printar tudo, e estou com dificuldade justamente em printar pois nao consigo comparar o objeto quadrado ou retangulo ou circulo com o ListaFormas[x], como eu fazia normalmente com um array, nem conseguindo retirar do ListaFormas qualquer objeto para poder trabalhar nele.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ArrayList ListaFormas = new ArrayList();
        Quadrado quadrado = new Quadrado();
        Retangulo retangulo = new Retangulo();
        Circulo circulo = new Circulo();

        Console.WriteLine("Quantas Formas deseja criar?(quadrado,retangulo ou circulo:");

        int quantidade = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for(int x = 0; x < quantidade; x++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Qual forma deseja criar?:");

            string nome = Console.ReadLine();

            if(nome == "quadrado" || nome == "Quadrado")
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Entre com o Lado do quadrado:");

               double lado = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
               quadrado.Lado = lado;

               ListaFormas.Add(quadrado);

            }
            else if(nome =="retangulo" || nome == "Retangulo")
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Entre com o primeiro lado:");
                double lado1 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Entre com o segundo lado:");
                double lado2 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                retangulo.Lado1 = lado1;
                retangulo.Lado2 = lado2;

                ListaFormas.Add(retangulo);
            }
            else if(nome == "circulo" || nome == "Circulo")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entre com o raio do circulo:");
                double raio = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                circulo.Raio = raio;

                ListaFormas.Add(circulo);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Erro opcao invalida");
            }


        }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Comparar o que? Sem uma definição clara do problema não tem como achar uma solução. Só este trecho já vejo vários problemas. Pode colocar as definições das 3 classes das formas para ajudar a gente melhorar seu código?

Comment: @Maniero "(...)pois nao consigo comparar o objeto quadrado ou retangulo ou circulo com o ListaFormas[x], como eu fazia normalmente com um array, nem conseguindo retirar do ListaFormas qualquer objeto para poder trabalhar nele.(...)".

Comment: @LP.Gonçalves isso não quer dizer nada.

Comment: Veja na documentação os métodos e propriedades que a classe [ArrayList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx) disponibiliza.

Comment: @Maniero se eu não entendi errado, acredito que ele gostaria de saber se `ListaFormas[x]` é um `Quadrado`, `Retangulo` ou `Circulo`. Posso estar equivocado.

Comment: @LP.Gonçalves pode até ser, mas nada indica com clareza que é isto.

Comment: e isso mesmo quero armazenar os objetos em um arraylist e comparar eles depois para ver se é quadrado reangulo ou circulo, para depois printar as informaçoes de cada um

Comment: @ArthurHenrique você quer uma solução baseado na sua pergunta ou quer aprender fazer do jeito certo?

Answer (score 1):

### Resposta simples

Faça sua lista um tipo genérico.

```
ListaFormas = new List<object>();
```

### Resposta completa

Quadrado, retângulo ou círculo, todos derivam do mesmo tipo, todos são Format Trigonométricas, então, a maneira ideal de chegar onde quer é definir primeiramente o que é uma forma trigonométrica.

```
public interface IFormaTrigonometrica
{
    float Altura { get; }
    float Largura { get; }
}
```

Em seguida, definir como será sua abstração.

```
public abstract class FormaTrigonometrica : IFormaTrigonometrica
{
    public float Altura { get; protected set; }
    public float Largura { get; protected set; }

    public FormaTrigonometrica(float altura, float largura)
    {
        if(altura <= 0 || largura <= 0) throw new ArgumentException("Formas trigonometricas devem ter tamanhos superiores à zero.");

        Altura = altura;
        Largura = largura;
    }
}
```

Assim, garantimos que qualquer forma trigonométrica, obrigatoriamente deverá ter `Altura` e `Largura` válidos.

Vamos agora definir alguns tipos de formas trigonométricas. Primeiro o círculo:

```
public class Circulo : FormaTrigonometrica
{
    public float Raio => base.Altura;

    public Circulo(float raio) : base(raio, raio)
    {
    }
}
```

Fica definido que um `Círculo` é uma forma trigonométrica, que só existe se tiver um raio, que por sua vez vale pela sua altura e largura.

Faremos o mesmo com o Retângulo:

```
public class Retangulo : FormaTrigonometrica
{
    public Retangulo(float ladoA, float ladoB) : base (ladoA, ladoA) 
    {
        if(ladoA == ladoB) throw new ArgumentException("Retangulo devem ter tamanho de lados diferentes");
    }
}
```

E por último com o `Quadrado`, que nada mais é que uma forma com lados iguais.

```
public class Quadrado : FormaTrigonometrica
{
    public float Lado => base.Altura;

    public Quadrado(float lado) : base (lado, lado) 
    {
    }
}
```

Agora, voce pode ter sua lista de formas trigonometricas:

```
var formas = new List<IFormaTrigonometrica>();

var circulo = new Circulo(10);
var quadrado = new Quadrado(5);
var retangulo = new Retangulo(7, 3);

formas.Add(circulo);
formas.Add(quadrado);
formas.Add(retangulo);

    for(var i = 0; i < formas.Count; i++)
    {
        var forma = formas[i];
        Console.Write($"Forma[{i}] => {forma.GetType()}");

        if(forma is Circulo)
            Console.Write($" com Raio {(forma as Circulo).Raio}");

        if(forma is Quadrado)
            Console.Write($" com Lado {(forma as Quadrado).Lado}");

        if(forma is Retangulo)
            Console.Write($" com Altura {(forma as Retangulo).Altura} e Largura {(forma as Retangulo).Largura}");

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Resultado:

```
Forma[0] => Circulo com Raio 10
Forma[1] => Quadrado com Lado 5
Forma[2] => Retangulo com Altura 7 e Largura 7
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CFlN89).

Comment: Thiago, não sei se posso fazer uma pergunta aqui, mas estava lendo sua resposta e não entendi o que significa o seguinte trecho: public Quadrado(float lado) : base (lado, lado).. Poderia me explicar por gentileza? Grato!

Comment: Isso é Herança. O Quadrado herda caracteristicas de FormaTrigonometrico. Mas FormaTrigonometrica exige 2 parameteros para ser construido - `float altura, float largura`. Quando se cria um `Quadrado` apenas com 1 parametro `Lado`, devemos passar para a classe base que ela deve ser construida com `altura` e `largura` com mesmo valores de `lado`.

Comment: Legal, nunca tinha visto essa usabilidade de herança. Obrigado!

Comment: muito obrigado thiago vou ver se consigo implementar isso aqui!! valeu!

Comment: consegui muito obrigado!

Comment: Legal! Não esqueça de marcar a resposta como ideal.